# ST_Disjoint() gives unexpected result using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am fiddling around with this dataset http://s3.cleverelephant.ca/postgis-workshop-2020.zip. It is used in this workshop http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html.

I want to identify all the census blocks, that do not have a subway station. I thought this spatial join is rather straight forward

```
SELECT
  census.boroname,
  census.geom
FROM nyc_census_blocks AS census
    JOIN nyc_subway_stations AS subway
        ON ST_Disjoint(census.geom, subway.geom);
```

However, the result set is way too large.

Why can't I identify all the census blocks that do not have a subway station?

I want to use `ST_Disjoint()` and not `ST_Intersects()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing each station to each census block and for each one returning all but one census block.

To fix this you need to union your stations together and then find the disjoint polygons.

```
SELECT
  census.boroname,
  census.geom
FROM nyc_census_blocks AS census
    JOIN (select st_union(geom) as geom from nyc_subway_stations) subway
        ON ST_Disjoint(census.geom, subway.geom);
```

Answer (score 3):

Joining on non-intersection is tricky. An `INNER JOIN` gathers a set of all matching rows between the tables; in this case, a **single row in `census`** matches with **every row in `subway`** that has an `ST_Disjoint` geometry!

In fact, it is better to tackle this the other way around, using `ST_Intersects` and an `EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT census.boroname,
       census.geom
FROM   nyc_census_blocks AS census
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   nyc_subway_stations AS subway
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(census.geom, subway.geom)
);
```

---

Alternatively, you could `SELECT DISTINCT`, but the `JOIN` is still highly inefficient.

Comment: Hmm, okay, that explains why it is so inefficient. However, I still want to run it with `ST_Disjoint()` in order to understand it. When I run the query from my Q, I get a table with many rows (that you explained why). However, when I visualize the result, there are only three geometries (census blocks) on the map... That should be way more. Why is that?

Comment: @Stophface visualizing this query, or the one in your question?

Comment: The query in my Q.

Comment: How do you visualize, using QGIS? In theory you should see the full coverage of census geometries - albeit duplicated some 490 times each. In practice, one does not simply render 18 million geometries - *especially* not from a cached query (note that QGIS will rerun the query each time you change the canvas).